# Where is android device chooser?

Tags: android, eclipse

I had selected a device in android device chooser, but now I want to change it.
It's funny but I can't find **Android Device Chooser** and let it ask for running on which device.
I tried to modify Run Config ( Check screenshot), but had no success.

[image: Eclipse Run Config Screenshot]

Where is it?

Comment: Did u run in the emulator or in a device?

Comment: I also had same issue beacuse "Use same device for further launches" was checked by mistake. I unchecked it and it started to prompt device chooser.

Answer (score 8):

Go to the project's properties, click the "Run/Debug configurations", Click "Edit...", Click the "Targets" tab and check "Always Prompt to pick device"

Comment: There is no debug configurations tab in project properties!

Comment: I've selected "Always prompt to pick device", but it still runs on my mobile and not my tablet!

Comment: Can you post the steps you followed? Which IDE are you using - Intellij or Android Studio or Eclipse?

Comment: Eclipse Juno, for screenshot check my question above. @Varundroid

Comment: Which minSDK you set in your project? There are good chances that because of minSDK it is not picking up the other device while deploying the project.

Comment: Nope, it's 8, and both my device are os 4+

Answer (score 2):

Close the emulator in which u ran the apk previously. Now run the application. The device chooser will appear. Unselect "Use same device for future launches in the bottom left corner". Then select a device. Restart your old emulator. When  "Use same device for future launches in the bottom left corner" is selected AFAIK there is no way of reverting the selected device.

Answer (score 0):

In eclipse, open "Run Configurations..."(Right click on Your Project -> Run as -> Run Configurations),
**double click** on your project in the Run Configuration dialog (In my case, double click project NuclideDetect):
[My eclipse screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/05mhr.png)
and the Android Device Chooser appears.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with Android Studio and this page was the only hit I found, so dropping the answer I came up with here.  You can get the device chooser back by going to the Run -> Edit Configurations menu, and setting the target for Deployment Target Options as shown here ...

[image: Run/Debug Configurations panel]

Answer (score 0):

For me I have to stop the current default device by pressing Run -> Stop button.

[image]

Only after I stopped the default device will Android Studio prompt me to pick a device when I click on the green run button.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You can click trl + F11 and Android Device Chooser will be shown